# comparing using multiple arguments in the Lower/Upper function

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to implement a query like below

```
        SELECT *
        FROM   emp
        WHERE  LOWER (ename) IN LOWER ('A', 'b', 'C', 'd','eF','GG','Hh');
```

but getting error

```
 ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments.
```

Is there any specific function by which I can compare multiple arguments in the 'IN' clause having lower case?

Comment: Why don't you use: `LOWER (ename) IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`?

Comment: I have mixed  type of arguments in my 'IN' clause for example: LOWER (ename) IN lower('aBC', 'aab', 'cDe', 'def'). So my trying to match both sides in a consistent way..

Comment: Where do those arguments come from? If they are constant values, what prevents you from writing them in lower case directly? If they come from some programming variables and this is actually dynamic SQL, then why can't you lower case them before building the dynamic SQL?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes i can do that, However I was wandering if we could compare multiple arguments in a single function at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Muhammad Muazzam has it right, but if for some reason you really need to user LOWER on the right hand side with a list of values then you could do this:

```
select ename from emp
where lower(ename) in 
(select lower(column_value) 
 from   table(SYS.KU$_VCNT('A','B','C','D'))
);
```

`SYS.KU$_VCNT` is a table of VARCHAR2(4000) type that should already exist in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Change query to:

```
SELECT *
        FROM   emp
        WHERE  LOWER (ename) IN ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Comment: my requirement is to get all the arguments on the right hand as lower to make equal comparison. They can be in in upper as well as lower case

Comment: @Dawn In case you only use literals in your value list, write them in lowercase. Otherwise, where do these values come from? Can you specify a subselect to get them as a single column using `LOWER` in the select clause?

Answer (score 1):

I would encourage you to phrase the query like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM emp
    WHERE ename IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

This allows Oracle to use an index on `ename`.  Note:  Oracle does allow indexes on expressions, so you could have an index on `lower(ename)` and use:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM emp
    WHERE ename IN (lower('A'), lower('B'), lower('C'), lower('D'));
```